# How to send Push notifications using parse.com (to Hybrid mobile apps)

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, cordova-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm working on a cross platform mobile app for a restaurant. I need to send push notifications to registered devices once a new order is received via my web application which is written in PHP. Only hotel staff would be registered/subscribed to receive the push.

I want to use parse.com in this process.

I would appreciate if i get help on how to send push messages to registered devices.

Thanks.

Comment: Please checkout  a guide how to ask a good question
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: have you followed the parse.com push notification tutorial and tried out the sample code they provide? What specific problems did you encounter when you did that?

Comment: @FoamyGuy, Thanks for the response. I'm clear on the part of configuration of push notification plugins with devices/app. I'm not clear about how to create push messages and send them over using parse. Do i have to integrate parse in my web application, where actual events are happening? or i have to read content from database to create push messages and send them over?

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment, you should use cloud code `afterSave` functions to dispatch notifications to the proper recipients.